# When Inserting into database only two row in datagridview been save in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

My problem here is every time i want to save into the database, only two row in the datagridview can be save. why is that ? is it because of the two command of inserting ?

Here is my code:

```
Try
    For Each column As DataGridViewRow In dtorder.Rows
        Dim sqlconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim sqlquery As String
        Dim sqlquery1 As String
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim cmd1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim connString As String
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Bloodyjenk\Documents\POS system.accdb"
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = connString

        sqlconn.Open()
        sqlquery = "INSERT INTO OrderedInfoName VALUES ('" & txtOrderNo.Text & "','" & column.Cells(0).Value & "','" & column.Cells(1).Value & "','" & column.Cells(2).Value & "','" & column.Cells(3).Value & "')"

        sqlquery1 = "INSERT INTO Ordered VALUES ('" & txtOrderNo.Text & "','" & cmbTable.Text & "','" & cmbOrdertype.Text & "','" & lblDate.Text & "','" & lblStatus.Text & "','" & lblPrice.Text & "','" & lblDiscount.Text & "','" & lblSub.Text & "', 0, 0)"

        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn)
        cmd1 = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery1, sqlconn)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlconn.Close()

    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("DONE")
    OrderList.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: Never concat SQL like that, use SQL Parameters.  What is `dtorder`?  Is it a DGV or a DataTable? Is the DGV (if there is one) bound?  Also if your code encounters an exception all you see is "DONE" -  get rid of the Try/Catch

Comment: Use parameters to avoid SQL injection and formatting errors.

Comment: it is DGV.  okayy will try it. thanks

Comment: My guess is that you are encountering a datatype conversion error, but the Catch is hiding it.  There is plenty that can be improved.

Comment: yeah, i got an error.  Data type mismatch in criteria expression when removing Try/Catch